# PYQT5: How to set splitter to a grid layout?

Tags: pyqt5, qgridlayout, qsplitter

I want to add a grid of plots to a splitter. I know how to set vertical (QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)) and horizontal (QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)) layouts to a splitter but not sure how to make it in grid layout.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? You can have "nested" QSplitters by adding (for example) horizontal QSplitters to a vertical one.

Comment: I figured that out by adding a widget to the splitter and setting widget layout to QGridlayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out like this:

```
self.plot_splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)

self.plot_grid = QGridLayout()
self.plot_widget = QWidget()
self.plot_widget.setLayout(self.plot_grid)

self.plot_splitter.addWidget(self.plot_widget)
```